# Google Charts Error 'Not An Array' on Ajax Update

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a simple Google chart which renders fine with the following data on initial page load:

```
[['days','AA','BB'], ['270',15,15],['240',19,19],['210',23,23],['180',31,31],['150',34,34],['120',47,47],['90',57,57],['60',71,71],['30',81,81],['0',94,94]]
```

When I attempt to refresh it via an Ajax call which currently returns **exactly** the same data I get an error 'not an array'.

This is my initial function which draws the chart correctly:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var chart;
      var options;

      google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var dataArray = ${initialChartData};
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

        options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Bookings by Days Before Holiday Start Date',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          }
        };

        chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

My Ajax Handler:

```
            $('#dataAnalysisForm').ajaxForm({
                success : function(responseText) {
                //error here as responseText 'is not an array'
                //it is the same String returned via Ajax as was 
                //used to render the initial chart
                //the initial data was written to the page server side. 
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(responseText);
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            });
```

What needs to change in the above code to make this work on initial page load and update correctly on Ajax response?

Comment: Just call `drawChart()` in `success` handler?

Comment: I fail to see what how that will work given that drawChart() refers to the initial data  ${initialChartData}

Answer (score 0):

Just do this again:

```
  var chart = new google.visualization.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
```

If your data is already in the right format there is no need to convert it, so you can use `chart.draw(responseText, options)`

Comment: See updated question. Specific issue is that I get an error 'not an array' with the Ajax response.

Comment: If the response is already in format of a DataTable use it directly. arrayToDataTable obviously won't work without an array.